# Doing minus operation on string

Tags: java, string

I have a small problem with the minus operation in java. When the user press the 'backspace' key, I want the char the user typed, to be taken away from the word which exists.
e.g
word = myname
*and after one backspace*
word = mynam

This is kinda of what I have:

```
String sentence = "";
char c = evt.getKeyChar();
if(c == '\b') {
  sentence = sentence - c;
} else {
  sentence = sentence + c;
}
```

The add operation works. So if I add a letter, it adds to the existing word. However, the minus isn't working. Am I missing something here? Or doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strings don’t have any kind of character subtraction that corresponds to concatenation with the `+` operator. You need to take a substring from the start of the string to one before the end, instead; that’s the entire string except for the last character. So:

```
sentence = sentence.substring(0, sentence.length() - 1);
```

Comment: awesome that makes sense. I tried using the '-' because the + was working. I couldn't find any reference on the web (probably there is something out there, just i didn't see)

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, Java supports string concatenation with the '+' sign. This is the one binary operator with a class type as an operand. See [String concatenation operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.18.1) in the Java Language Specification.

Java does not support an overload of the '-' operator between a String and a char.

Instead, you can remove a character from a string by adding the substrings before and after.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentance = sentance.substring(0, sentance.length() - 1);
```

There is no corresponding operator to + which allows you to delete a character from a String.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate the StringBuilder class, eg:

```
StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder();
```

Then you can do something like:

```
sentence.append(a);
```

for a new character or

```
sentence.deleteCharAt(sentence.length() - 1);
```

Then when you actually want to use the string, use:

```
String s = sentence.toString();
```